# Drupal - Site Building, Menus

Tags: drupal

I'm working with Drupal for the first time and trying to figure out how to change the Menu item names through the Administer Site Building configuration menus.

I have logged into the Drupal admin site and navigated to > Administer/ Site Building/ Menus, select the menu item and click Edit, change the Title from , 'About' to 'About Us' however when loading the site page it still says 'About'

Please pardon my lack of understanding on drupal, i am somewhat familiar with joomla another CMS however I just need some pointers in the right direction as to how to edit the links and rename them within drupal.  the links are not images as far as i can tell while viewing the source and properties on the links.

Thank you!

Comment: As mentioned, caching is usually the answer to anything not working as expected in Drupal.  Logged-in users shouldn't ordinarily have pages cached, anonymous ones will.  Drush comes in really handy during development work - being able to run 'drush cache clear' if something isn't behaving correctly is really nice.

Oh also, make sure the menus aren't hard-coded and that they are loading the names dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a caching issue either with your browser.  Shift + reload in most browsers tell it to skip the browser's cache.

Drupal has it's own cache that it keeps but this tends to be theme related stuff as templates and css optimizations and not content itself.  But for completeness sake.  To clear Drupal's cache you want to go to Admin->Site Configuration->Performance and at the bottom is a clear cached button.

Edit:  How aggressive Drupal caches is based on a setting on that same page.  Also if you use the [Administration menu module](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) if you go to the favicon in the menu it will give you an option to flush all caches as well as individual caches....one of these is the menu cache.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  The caching is a big help, I have turned it off in the meantime while I work on renaming our menu items.   However it seems like it has not done the trick.   I've changed a few menu items names and even tried to reposition their sorting order.   The repositioning is working but the names are still staying the same.

Comment: When working on web development I normally use Firefox with the web developer tool bar which gives you an option to disable the browser cache.  This just prevents me from chasing non-issues.  If the menu items are showing up in a different order then I don't think the menu name issue is a browser caching issue.  I know this sounds dumb but are you sure you're saving the edits you're doing to the menu name?  I can't think of anything else that would prevent a menu item from being modified.

Comment: They are being saved, I am able to make changes renaming or edits to sub category menus however unable to rename the top level menus which are bound to Top Nav. I can change their sorting order and I also tested to see if i can disable them which works too.  But the names are staying as their defaults they were originally set to.

Comment: I just found out that the top nav page i am trying to edit is using a module called 'Nice Menus' now at this point i'm trying to figure out how to rename an object in nice menus.

Comment: I use nice menus on my Drupal websites.  It doesn't change how you manage the menus.  That module just adds css and javascript to do the dynamic dropdown bits.  If you go admin->site building->blocks and then hit configure on the nice menu that you're trying to edit it will tell you what menu it's using for it's menu.  Any edits to that referenced menu should show up in the nice menu version of that menu.